# RDD transformation inside a loop

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

So i have an rdd:Array[String] named Adat and I want to transform it within a loop and get a new RDD which I can use outside the loop scope.I tried this but the result is not what I want.

```
val sharedA = {
  for {
    i <- 0 to shareA.toInt - 1  
    j <- 0 to shareA.toInt - 1 
  } yield { 
    Adat.map(x => (x(1).toInt, i % shareA.toInt, j % shareA.toInt, x(2))) 
  }  
}
```

The above code transforms the SharedA rdd to IndexedSeq[RDD[(Int, Int, Int, String)]] and when i try to print it the result is:

```
MapPartitionsRDD[12] at map at planet.scala:99

MapPartitionsRDD[13] at map at planet.scala:99  and so on.
```

How to transform sharedA to `RDD[(Int, Int, Int, String)]`?

If i do it like this the sharedA has the correct datatype but i cannot use it outside the scope.

```
      for { i <- 0 to shareA.toInt -1 
      j<-0 to shareA.toInt-1 } 
      yield   { 
      val sharedA=Adat.map(x => (x(1).toInt,i % shareA.toInt ,j %      
      shareA.toInt,x(2)))    
       }
```

Comment: I don't understand what is the point of your code :(  `i % shareA.toInt`, `j % shareA.toInt` should be simply equal to `i` and `j` respectively and are the only changing element. Could you provide example input and expected output.

Comment: the shareA is calculated already and consider it as a small Integer but its not important, lets say the RDD Adat at start have  some data seperated by comma,with the help of the loop i want to add with a map more data using the i and j and i want to get the result to a new RDD which i could use outside the scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't exactly understand your description but `flatMap` should do the trick:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(Array("", "0", "foo"), Array("", "1", "bar")))
val n = 2

val result = rdd.flatMap(xs => for {
  i <- 0 to n
  j <- 0 to n
} yield (xs(1).toInt, i, j, xs(2)))

result.take(5)
// Array[(Int, Int, Int, String)] =
//   Array((0,0,0,foo), (0,0,1,foo), (0,0,2,foo), (0,1,0,foo), (0,1,1,foo))
```

Less common approach would be to call `SparkContext.union` on the results:

```
val resultViaUnion = sc.union(for {
  i <- 0 to n
  j <- 0 to n
} yield rdd.map(xs => (xs(1).toInt, i, j, xs(2))))

resultViaUnion.take(5)
// Array[(Int, Int, Int, String)] = 
// Array((0,0,0,foo), (1,0,0,bar), (0,0,1,foo), (1,0,1,bar), (0,0,2,foo))
```